# How to get zooming, panning, and rotating to work for image in scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiimageview

So I want to display an image that a user can zoom, pan, and rotate.

I want the image to fit to the screen (i.e. aspect ratio is maintained, the entire image is visible on the screen, and 2 opposite edges of the image are touching the edge of the screen).

When the screen rotates I would like the behaviour to be maintained.

I've played around with quite a few settings but can't get the perfect behaviour.

What I currently have:

A `UIScrollView` with a `UIImageView` as its child.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test2.jpg"];
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
}

- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    CGFloat width = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.scrollView.frame.size.height;

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
    {
        NSLog(@"Screen rotated to landscape orientation.");
        self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, height, width);

        [self.scrollView setZoomScale:1 animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Screen rotated to portrait orientation.");
        self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

        [self.scrollView setZoomScale:1 animated:YES];
    }
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageView;
}
```

The behaviour of this current code works quite well for me when in portrait mode. The image fits to the screen and is centred. The behaviour for landscape just doesn't work the way I want it to.

I don't really understand why `[self.scrollView setZoomScale:1 animated:YES];` works at all. It seems to work for images of any size. Maybe I don't quite understand what the zoomScale does/is?

Answer (score 0):

I just put a a repo on GitHub that does just that. It is in Swift but it should do

[PhotoSlideShow-Swift](https://github.com/villyg/PhotoSlideShow-Swift)